# MySql - increment column when there is a duplicate key

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to create a table with 3 columns(Group_Name, Member, Position). When I am populating this table from another table in the DB, the columns Group_Name( political parties) will contain duplicates. When a duplicate occurs the Position will be incremented by 1. For example:

```
Group_Name | Member     |     Position
------------------------------
democrats  |   joe b    |         1
democrats  |  mark d    |         2
democrats  |  owen l    |         3
republican |  esther d  |         1
republican |  tom d     |         2
republican |  ryan g    |         3
republican |  tea d     |         4
pirate     |  bun r     |         1
```

I created the table with Group_Name and Position being primary keys.

```
CREATE TABLE Group_Membership ( Group_Name varchar(255) NOT NULL, Member varchar(255) NOT NULL, Position int, PRIMARY KEY (Group_Name, Position));
```

Then when I'm inserting the data, every time there is a duplicate the position should update by 1.

```
INSERT INTO Group_Membership(Group_Name, Member, Position) SELECT group_affiliation.value, group_affiliation.name, 1 FROM group_affiliation ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Position = Position + 1;
```

But I am getting an error:

```
Duplicate entry 'The Republican Party-2' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

I presume this is because Position key is not aware of the entry before it.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated as this is driving me crazy!

Comment: You can use something like a rank function over a group. It's not straightforward to do in mysql but searching for how to use rank in mysql should give you a lot of results.

Comment: If you were to use the MyISAM engine, this would be automatic, but it's not what I'd do. I'd just store an autoincrementing id and calculate the ranking when querying

Comment: Thanks Strawberry the MyISAM engine worked a treat :)

Answer (score 0):

Check max position inside trigger before insert like this :

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER updatePosition BEFORE INSERT ON Group_Membership
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    SET NEW.Position = (
       SELECT IFNULL(MAX(Position), 0) + 1
       FROM Group_Membership
       WHERE Group_Name  = NEW.Group_Name
    );
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: FWIW, I think this is a bad idea.